# Unable to start websphere server in RAD

Tags: websphere-8, rad

I have a problem with WebSphere Application Server 8.5, I am not able to start it, when I try to start it I get the following error:

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, I increased the start time to 300s but still cannot launch the server.

Is there someone who can help to resolve this issue please ?

Comment: So you're using the "Web preview server" (translated to English) option.  Do you see anything in the "Console" tab?

Comment: @ScottKurz a message indicating that the server is starting when I click start, and when the popup shows up nothing is displayed in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem reinstalling RAD (Rational Application Developer), and the server started without error within 50s

Answer (score 0):

`Web preview server` is not WAS server. You have to right-click in the `Server` view and select `Add` and create new WebSphere Application Server server, pointing to existing WAS 8.5 installation.